# Production not finding certain gem methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, production-environment

I've added added the gem [simple-navigation 3.9.0](http://rubygems.org/gems/simple-navigation) to my gemfile in **rails 3.2.11** and it runs fine in development. However, when I deploy to my production server and try to open a page with the method I get the following error:

```
undefined method `render_navigation'
```

I don't believe it's specific to that one gem though, as I had the same problem earlier when I used the [uuid gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/uuid).

Using $LOADED_FEATURES I find **"simple_navigation"**, so it seems to be loaded.

**Info about the production server**

```
nginx 1.2.6
Unicorn 4.5.0
Rubygems 1.8.23
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
rbenv 0.4.0-9-g045f6c1
```

**EDIT**

Other gems work, the server runs fine, except for the above problem.

Comment: Do you need to reboot the production server?

Comment: That was my first thought, but I`ve restarted both nginx and unicorn with no luck. I`ve even re-installed nginx after I got the error to compile it with mp4-support without any change.

Comment: Where did you put your `navigation.rb` file?

Comment: in the /config folder. However I'm actually using a file called sidebar_static_navigation.rb and the plain navigation.rb file for that view. navigation.rb still exists though.

Comment: did you do the `rake assets:precompile` ?

Comment: That's done automatically on deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While technically not an answer, I decided to switch over to Linode as my host. This involved a complete re-install of my server setup and it's working now. I did the exact same steps installing the server this time as last, so I'm still not sure what was wrong, or if it would have been easily fixable. Since I no longer have the old server available it would be impossible to confirm any solutions proposed from now on.

I'm going to mark this answer as the solution unless there are any objections within the next 48 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your gem is not declared inside the `development` group in the Gemfile

The gems in the `development` group are not be loaded in `production`.

```
group :development do
  gem "simple-navigation"
end
```

Also, if you have a `<APP_HOME>/.bundle/config` file, ensure that it doesn't have the `BUNDLE_WITHOUT` option.

**Gemfile**

```
group :ui do
  gem "simple-navigation"
end
```

**.bundle/config**

```
---
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: ui
```

In the above example, the gem group `ui` will not be loaded.

Comment: It's not in any specific groups in the Gemfile and should be loaded by all environments.

Answer (score 0):

Having said that I had very-very limited exposure to Rails, I saw similar behavior when Gemfile.lock wasn't committed into repository. As result when project was pushed to production envinronment there was some screw ups with dependency resolution.

Comment: I've made sure the Gemfile.lock file exists and are of the latest version (includes the simple-navigation gem), I also found the gem in console by using $LOADED_FEATURES.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try `RAILS_ENV=production bundle install` ?